# How to use experimental decorators and reconcile types in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following basic component

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { withRouter, RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';

export interface Props { };

@withRouter
export default class Movies extends React.PureComponent<Props> {
  goBack = () => {
    this.props.history.goBack();
  };

  public render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.goBack}>Back</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I would expect `withRouter` to inject specific props into my component. However, when referencing `this.props.history`, I get this:

[image]

What is the appropriate way to use decorators which will add type definitions?

Comment: This is a tracked issue with ts https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881

Answer (score 1):

I do it this way:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { withRouter, RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';

export interface OwnProps { };

type Props = OwnProps & RouteComponentProps<{}>;

@withRouter
export default class Movies extends React.PureComponent<Props> {
  goBack = () => {
    this.props.history.goBack();
  };

  public render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.goBack}>Back</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```